# Examples of creative and useful operator use in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

Following a discussion with a friend about operator overloading. I am looking at creative and/or useful example usage of operator overloading in Scala. I have some cool illustrations:

- Mathematical constructs, like linear algebra or complex numbers (`+ * -`)
- Mimicking shell pipe and redirections (`| > < >>`)
- Alternative expressions in Grammars (`|`)

Have you other nice examples ?

Comment: Too much creativity is usually a bad thing, since it violates expectations.  Operator overloading is most powerful when it is used just like everyone would expect: yes, of course `*` multiplies complex numbers as well as doubles!  For example, naming your return variable `frodo` and a temporary swap variable `sam` is creative in a sense, but is pretty incomprehensible (especially to people unfamiliar with the Lord of the Rings).  Naming your return variable `<---` and your swap variable `<-->` is probably not much better.

Comment: For those new to Scala, keep in mind that Scala's "operator syntax" is just a nice way of calling ordinary Scala methods. So `x + y` is the same as `x.+(y)`. In both cases, `+` is an ordinary method on object `x`, which could be of type `Int`, `Double`, etc. The operator syntax doesn't need a symbolically named method (e.g., `list1 zip list2` works), but using a symbolically named method allows Scala to apply built-in precedence rules.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is still not accepting "list all your favorite X for Y" questions. Unless your current problem is *I need to list all operators* or some such, this is out of scope according to the [faq].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ones I don't mind using occasionally:

- A general-purpose pipe `|>` (e.g., `someValue |> println`)
- `:=` one some structures like observable value holders to mimic assignment
- Databinding in UI programming with `<=>` (two-way), `<==` (one-way) (e.g., `field.enabled <=> options.isEditable`

Answer (score 4):

I find useful two "built-in" operators in Scala: `::` and `->`.

In maps creation, you can write `Map("a" -> 1)` and Scala translates `"a" -> 1` into `("a", 1)` tuple.
`::` is used for appending in front of List, it's also very convenient.

Also `+=` and `-=` operators for collections are great, especially because they apply to mutable and immutable ones as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit a controversial topic in the scala community. One the one side people fear abuse could lead to incomprehensible programs. If you think
seriously about it it already exists. Because what operators feel ‘naturally’? So lets take mathematical Operators: + - * /
So why in ‘most’ programming languages + is defined on Strings ?

On the other side ‘well’ known operators could lead to more concise and comprehensible code. Scala supports unicode symbols so you could use symbols like /u+2211.
Example:
List(1,2,3).sum //would give us 6, using sum instead of /u+2211 because lacking unicode keyboard support.

So instead of 3 characters (s,u,m) we have one (/u+2211) Is this good or bad? In my opinion scala community will find a common sense on this topic but it will take some time.

Other programming languages which support unicode expressions include fortress.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I [showed](http://dev.day.com/microsling/content/blogs/main/scalajcr4.html) how to create a DSL with operators to manipulate the nodes and properties of a [JCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java) tree. If laid out correctly the code resembles an ASCII art drawing of the actual content tree. The following Scala code

```
root ¦- "movies" -+ { n: Node =>
                n ¦= ("title", "Night on Earth")
                n ¦= ("length", 123L)
                n ¦= ("ratings", 9L::8L::5L::Nil)
                n ¦= ("languages", "en"::"it"::"fi"::"fr"::Nil) 
                n ¦- "cast" -+ { n: Node =>
                           n ¦= ("Gena Rowlands", "Victoria Snelling")
                           n ¦= ("Winona Ryder", "Corky")
                           n ¦= ("Roberto Benigni", "Taxi Driver") }}
```

is equivalent to this version in Java:

```
    Node movies = root.addNode("movies");
    movies.setProperty("title", "Night on Earth");
    movies.setProperty("length", 123L);
    movies.setProperty("ratings", new String[]{"9", "8", "5"}, PropertyType.LONG);
    movies.setProperty("languages", new String[]{"en", "it", "fi", "fr"}, PropertyType.STRING);
    Node cast = movies.addNode("cast");
    cast.setProperty("Gena Rowlands", "Victoria Snelling");
    cast.setProperty("Winona Ryder", "Corky");
    cast.setProperty("Roberto Benigni", "Taxi Driver");
```

While not necessarily useful, it might deserve a point for creativity.

Comment: If you indented the Java version like the Scala version, it wouldn't look so bad...